# Determining Markov transition matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, matrix-equations

Unsure if my attempt is correct, pasted the information below

Problem entails a Markov transition matrix worded question which I find a little tricky.

Problem + my attempt
https://imgur.com/a/Nxl8l9f

Comment: Where are you having particular difficulty?

Comment: im just unsure, a friend of mine got a different matrix so it's like who's right type of thing haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with a pedestrian approach:
A letter is followed by another letter with probability 0.8. 
If it is a vowel, it is followed by a consonant with probability 0.64 (0.8*0.8) overall.
If it is a consonant, it is followed by a vowel with probability 0.4 overall.
So we already have
$$ P(V,C) = 0.64, P(V,V) = 0.16, P(C, V) = 0.4, P(C,C) = 0.4, $$
which corresponds to your first 4 values. Since $0.2*0.9 = 0.18$ this is the probability for a letter to be followed by a blank space. Hence it remains a probability $0.02$ to be followed by a punctuation mark.
The last hypotheses gives exacty what you have.

Remember that one of the easiest thing to check when you are writting a transition matrix as this one is that the sum of each line must be equal to one (starting from anywhere, we must go somewhere). On the other hand there is no requisite on the sum of each column.

Comment: thanks appreciate it, i was breaking my mind over if i was correct or not.